# RDS Aurora Mysql Cluster - ALTER TABLE - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Whe I try to alter my table (700 GB in total), I got an error after 2 hours like "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

My query looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE add column x ...
```

Note: There isn't a storage/size problem.

**Solved with Amazon DMS.**

Comment: Which client are you using to run this? Some clients have execution time limits. When I run a long-running SQL statement on RDS, I would run it from the command-line mysql client in a `tmux` session on an EC2 instance in the same region and VPC as the RDS instance. Then there should be no timeout and no possibility of network interruption.

Comment: ran from the same VPC. I'll observe it and I'll write the results.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with using **Amazon DMS**.

1. Created new table with new column
2. Migrated data with DMS from existing table to new table with `select insert into`
3. Deleted old table
4. Renamed new table